# Configuring PIP to work from behind a proxy

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I've installed python 3.4.3 which comes with `pip`. I want to use pip from behind a proxy so I did the following:

Created `C:\Users\foo\pip\pip.ini` and added a proxy configuration section:

```
[proxy]
export http_proxy=my_proxy_server:1234
```

However, when I try to run pip to install packages, I get timeout messages:

> C:\Users\foo>pip install paramiko Requirement already satisfied (use
>   --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko in c:\python3 4\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.16.0-py3.4.egg Collecting
>   pycrypto!=2.4,>=2.1 (from paramiko)   Retrying (Retry(total=4,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec tion broken by
>   'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to
>   pypi.python. org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pycrypto/

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in Adv.!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following command so that pip uses your proxy. The basic format is of this form:

```
 [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port
```

For example:

```
pip --proxy http://<your proxy>:<your port> (for http)
pip --proxy https://<your proxy>:<your port> (for https)
```

Comment: Thanks, Arpri. This seems to get me one step further but now I get this:  "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pycrypto!=2.4,>=2.1
(from paramiko)
  No distributions at all found for pycrypto!=2.4,>=2.1 (from paramiko)"

Comment: @Arpit Goyal Can this settings be saved in pip.ini file?

Comment: you can check in pip's documentation the portion about config file https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

Answer (score 3):

You can set the proxy in "/etc/pip.conf":

```
[global]
proxy = http://host:port
```