# pip does not install wheels from pypi.org (firewall)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, protocols, firewall

I have Python 3.6 and pip 10.0.1 installed on Windows 8. I am behind corporate firewall. Pip installs downloaded whls locally, no problem. But when I try to install wheels from Internet typing e.g. `pip install sql` , I get the following:

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None))  after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a
>   new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/sql/
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sql (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for sql

**Main Question:** what exact firewall settings/exceptions shall I advise IT team to make pip work? 
**Dependent questions:** 
- What protocol pip uses to download modules?
- Connection to what port should be opened/forwarded?
- Can this be solved via proxy server?

Studied these topics, tried to use, did not help much:

[Pip not working behind firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468550)

[Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422)

[Configuring PIP to work from behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782673)

[What ports does pip use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377175)

Comment: can you check your pip version (`pip -V`)

Comment: `pip 9.0.3 from c:\users\<...>\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)`

Comment: @Anupam, I updated pip to 10.0.1 - no changes

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --proxy <address:port> <modulename>
```

Actually, [Configuring PIP to work from behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782673/configuring-pip-to-work-from-behind-a-proxy) gives correct answer. And I used wrong proxy address.